# How should I name methods for this sample code?

Tags: java, methods

I have several java API methods, such as:

```
SellApple.java
BuyApple.java
SellOrange.java
BuyHospital.java
```

I have reorganized using  `static inner class` for better understanding:

```
public static class Fruit{
      public static class Apple{
         public static class Buy{}
         public static class Sell{}
      }

      public static class Orange{
         public static class Buy{}
         public static class Sell{}
      }
```

So I can find the `api` easily by `Fruid.Apple.Buy`, But for another name methods:

```
public static class Fruit{

      public static class Apple{
           public static class BuyApple{}
           public static class SellApple (}
      }
      public static class Orange{
           public static class BuyOrange{}
           public static class SellOrange{}
      }
```

So which is better?  Buy or BuyOrange? for usage, use Buy is more easy, but use buyorange is more detail.

it is a discuss only for Buy or BuyOrange, not if I should add methods into the class or use name word instead of verb word.

maybe my example is not for my purpose. My question is if I use inner class. should I static had need to add outer class info for inner class?

if no need, I can only use Buy, if need, I should use BuyApple.

Comment: If you have inner classes delcard as static, you won't be able to access the containing classes attributes and properties. Is that not an issue for you? also, there are lots of parentheses missing I think!

Comment: @ha9u63ar, no my issue is which name is better?

Comment: @jjafu         using BUy is more appropriate for API purposes

Comment: I'd put `buy()` in an `interface` and have all fruit inherit it.  The whole inner class thing looks a little strange to me.

Comment: @markspace  I like the idea.  I would possibly add a factory that serves up a singleton for each fruit.

Comment: "How should I name methods" <-- generally, in Java, this follows the camelCase convention; that is, write `buy` and not `Buy`; write `buyMeat` and not `BuyMeat` etc.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't have any methods in your code?

Answer (score 2):

My personal suggest is :

1. use buy().
2. define buy() in an separate Interface file.
3. Don't define Fruit as a class, but a package.

Comment: maybe my example is not for my purpose. My question is if I use inner class. should I had need to add outer class info for inner class?